# Function returning value after being initiated from Start-Job -ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, jobs

Imagine you created function that returns Boolean value (e.g. `Set-SomeConfiguration`). Then, you call that function with

```
Start-Job -Scriptblock { Set-SomeConfiguration -ComputerName $computer }
```

Is there any way of retrieving the Boolean value generated by `Set-SomeConfiguration`?

Comment: Are you not just looking for `Receive-Job`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using the [`Receive-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849718.aspx) cmdlet:

```
$SomeJob = Start-Job { Set-SomeConfiguration -ComputerName $computer }
$Result  = $SomeJob | Receive-Job -Wait
```

The `-Wait` parameter ensures that `Receive-Job` waits for the job to finish and return its results.

(*Note: most `Set-*` cmdlets won't - and shouldn't - actually return anything. To achieve what you describe, you could return the value of the [automatic variable `$?`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx): `{Set-SomeConfiguration;$?}`, or inspect the `State` and `Error` properties of the job before receiving*)

---

If you want more granular control over how long you want to wait, use [`Wait-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849735.aspx).

In this example, we wait for 10 seconds (or until the job has finished):

```
# Job that takes a variable amount of time
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $(5..15 | Get-Random)
    return "I woke up!"
}

# Wait for 10 seconds
if(Wait-Job $Job -Timeout 10){
    # Job returned before timeout, let's grab results
    $Results = $Job | Receive-Job 
} else {
    # Job did not return in time
    # You can log, do error handling, defer to a default value etc. in here
}

# Clean up
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```